# Instantiate an object in an IF condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, coding-style

I have a class that has a method `CheckValues(someVar)` which returns true or false after taking in a parameter which is being checked for null or empty first. This class's method is called in a WCF service running off IIS and also in a multi-threaded application. Which of the two ways below is better?

1:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();

if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(someVar) && obj.CheckValues(someVar))
{
    ...
}
```

2:

```
if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(someVar) && new MyClass().CheckValues(someVar))
{
    ...
}
```

The first method is pretty conventional. The second gives me the benefit of creating an object only if the variable `someVar` has some value, not otherwise.

Is there any problem with the second approach, or is it bad practice? Will it matter if this variable is either a value type or a reference type?

Comment: SO should really reign in these "format fundamentalists" from randomly down voting without giving a valid reason from their predefined list of valid reasons for down voting!

Comment: I thought it was reasonable (and am the upvote), though you could argue its opinion based (is this a good design? it often depends on who you ask). +1/-2 isn't too bad, though I always like getting a comment when downvoted as well.

Comment: I agree Bradley. Downvotes should mandate a reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything inherently bad about the second code snippet. In fact, as you have noted, it would be a small optimization over the first.

That said, it *smells* bad. Why are you creating an object for exactly one use, to call a method with no parameters? Should that method be static, as it doesn't need state? Should you just reuse an existing object?

The main problem I see is that the existence of that logic indicates a problem somewhere else in your design.

To your comments:

1. The existence of a parameter doesn't really change the smell; as you are still making a one-time use object for a single function call.
2. Given your second comment, the design *could* be reasonable. Make sure that object does *nothing* but generate the state necessary to handle the check though. If it is some large object, you just introduced a bunch of overhead for nothing.

Comment: Actually there are parameters to the method. I was not sure it mattered so didn't put the full code there. I will update the question shortly

Comment: Further to your query: "Why are you creating an object for exactly one use..", That class has a method that can possibly be used elsewhere in the application and so I don't want its logic to stay in this class. It takes a variable that will be checked against a back end database. I am not thinking of a static class here because I want this class to work in a web or multi-threaded environment too

Comment: In the current scope of work, that method will be called just once. I just need to check some value I send in. The class has other methods too, but not of any importance to this particular scope of work. Lets just say for sake of simplicity, I want to check the string username is logged in or not. This function can be used in other places too, but here just once. I don't need it more than one time. Should objects only be created if they are used multiple times within a class?

Comment: I dont want my PrintUserActivityReport class to check for user logged in as that would probably violate Single responsibility.. PrintUserActivityReport should only print UserActivity when told to. sometimes it might be printed for logged in users, othertimes it may not. This is perhaps not the best example of showing how the PrintUserActivityReport() class calling MyClass() are not related to doing the same thing. Also MyClass().CheckValues(someVar) will be used in other classes too. I dont want to have that logic in the PrintUserActivityReport() class.

Comment: @user20358 Again, the answer is *it depends*. It sounds like this is a DB access class, so instantiating and calling one function is probably fine, as there shouldn't be much overhead. If this was a different kind of object, my answer would differ. For your scenario, you are probably okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `CheckValues()` static method and then you won't have to make object of class to call it.

Comment: Yea a static method seems better unless something is precluding that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: will that work in the context of a WCF service running off IIS when multiple requests could be calling that method indirectly. The method actually takes in a parameter. I will update the question shortly..

Comment: I answered generally for your question, If there are details then share them.